# Question about notation for filtration of $\sigma$-algebras.

Tags: stochastic-processes, notation

In section 1.8 of Sidney Resnick's Adventures in Stochastic Processes, he writes

> In general, suppose we have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$, and an increasing family of $\sigma$-fields $\mathcal F_n,n\geqslant0$; i.e., $\mathcal F_n\subset F_{n+1}$. Define
>   $$ \mathcal F_{\infty} = \bigvee_{n\geqslant 0}\mathcal F_n := \sigma\left(\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty\mathcal F_n\right).$$

What does $\bigvee_{n\geqslant 0}\mathcal F_n$ denote? Is it just shorthand for the expression on the right?

Comment: Well, ":=" usually means that we *define* the expression on the left-hand side by the right-hand side, right?

Comment: Yes, but I don't really understand the use of the symbol $\bigvee$. Isn't that normally used to denote a maximum or supremum?

Comment: In case you see it in some other places: The notation is used in general with partially ordered sets: $a\vee b$ denotes the smallest $c$ such that $c\geq a$ and $c\geq b$. In this case the partially ordered set is the collection of sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\leq$ is $\subset$. That is why it coincides with the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the union: the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all of the $\mathcal{F}_n$.

Comment: @Math1000 Basically it's a supremum: It's the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which contains all $\mathcal{F}_n$. (Compare this with real numbers: The supremum $\sup_n f_n$ is the smallest number which is larger (or equal) than $f_n$ for all $n$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, $\vee$ denotes the maximum; more generally,

$$\bigvee_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n = \sup\{f_n; n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

is  the supremum of a sequence of real numbers $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, i.e. $\bigvee_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n$ is the smallest number which is larger or equal than $f_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Here the situation is quite similar:

$$\bigvee_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{F}_n = \sigma \left( \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{F}_n \right)$$

is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which contains all $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{F}_n$. In this sense, we can see $\bigvee_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{F}_n$ as a supremum.